# 17.10 Freezing When Moving Windows

Tags: multiple-monitors, 17.10, freeze

This issue occurred both before and after I did a fresh install of Ubuntu Desktop 17.10.
I have a dual monitor setup 27" and 24" using a GTX 970.

When I am moving a window around either by clicking and dragging or by using keyboard shortcuts to snap the window to different sizes/screens, my computer will occasionally lock up. The only way to recover is to hard reboot.

I can replicate the issue almost every time by clicking and dragging a window from one screen to the other. It crashes almost immediately after I cross into the second monitor.

I've tried reinstalling nvidia drivers and running apt-get update/upgrade but I continue to have this same problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I am also getting this issue. It seems to be when dragging a window with a video playing in it. I am also on an nvidia card (gtx 770).

Comment: I have the same problem. For me it happens on both Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 using a company proprietary application we have developed internally using Qt 5.15.8, VTK 8.2.0, CUDA 11.2, NVIDIA driver 510.47.03

Comment: @nocnokneo You really should ask your own question and supply your own specifics.  A complicated window, may be trying to redraw itself every pixel, so a rubber-band type move would be better in that case.

Comment: @nocnokneo I agree with previous comment, your own question is warranted. None-the-less I still posted an answer below that hopefully sheds some light on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult answering a question about Ubuntu `17.10` when the real person now is using `18.04 and` 20.04`.

The platform is `QT` and there are know bugs with HiDPI monitors and scaling:

- [Moving QMPlay2 window to another display breaks playback](https://github.com/zaps166/QMPlay2/issues/155)

This is just one example of many QT bugs out in the "wild". Personally I use Tkinter instead and am quite pleased with it. Lately though I've branched into JavaScript for a more global audience.

In any respect, save your bounty next time by posting your own detailed specific question. Then others can ask questions in comments and narrow it down.